# strange behavior of countdown time in python/tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, countdown

```
import tkinter as ttk

import random, time

def question1(*args):
        waitmsg= "You must wait for " + str(random.randrange(20,240,5)) + " minutes"
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text=(waitmsg), width=30).grid(column=1, row=3)
        countdown()
        # go do a bunch of stuff

def question2(*args):
    waitmsg= "WAIT " + str(root.wait_time) + " minutes"
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=(waitmsg), width=30).grid(column=1, row=3)
        countdown()

def countdown(*args):
    # intended to display the remaining time as it counts down

    # the print works right away (no dealy!)
    print (root.wait_time)

    # the Label waits for a full 5 seconds then displays a 0 wait time!

    waitmsg= "WAIT count " + str(root.wait_time) + " minutes"
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=(waitmsg), width=30).grid(column=1, row=3)
    if root.wait_time >= 1 :
        root.wait_time -= 1
        root.after(1000, countdown())
    else:     
        root.wait_time=5
    return


root = ttk.Tk()
root.title("Choose question!")
root.wait_time = 0

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
if root.wait_time == 0:
##    root.wait_time= random.randrange(20,240,5)
    root.wait_time=5
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="question2?", command=question2).grid(column=4, row=1)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="question1?", command=question1).grid(column=1, row=1)



root.bind('<Return>', question2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Sorry I thought it was correctly formatted! It runs as is. The original was set up by IDLE

Comment: Can you please formulate a clear question. Please do not expect people to read through your code without some short summary and clearly formulated question. Some comment like 'go do a bunch of stuff' is not helpful..

Comment: You are calling `after` incorrectly. There are many related questions on this site.

Comment: I will try again to improve the comments and description. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like I need to read more on after then! At least that is a place to start. THank you!

Comment: The main issue is that you use result of `countdown()` as the callback function in the statement `root.after(1000, countdown())`.  You should just pass the function name: `root.after(1000, countdown)`.

Answer (score 1):

> The main issue is that you use result of countdown() as the callback function in the statement root.after(1000, countdown()). You should just pass the function name: root.after(1000, countdown). – acw1668

This appears to fix the problem. Thank you!

It also appears that  have a lot to learn about tkinter and stackoverflow :-)